# Что использовать в Qt close() или destroy()?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, pyqt

Всем привет! 
Подскажите что использовать для закрытия окон в Qt? Я использую сразу обе функции для полного закрытия окна
self.close() и self.destroy() 
Почему я так делаю: 
1) Я написал приложение в котором вызывается диалоговое окно, и при нажатии на кнопку строиться таблица из 1,000,000 элементов. Так вот если использовать просто close(), то при повторном вызове этого диалогового окна таблица остается заполненной!(То есть сохраняется старая заполненная таблица) 
Из этого выходит второй пункт
2) При использовании только close(), память не освобождается. Таблица из 1,000,000 элементов остается в памяти.

При использовании self.close() и self.destroy() одновременно, таких проблем нет, поэтому я сейчас все окно закрываю таким способом.
Посвятите неуча пожалуйста, правильно ли я делаю?

Comment: А просто destroy() не закрывает окно?

Comment: Закрывает. Но если закрыть Гланое окно то программа остается запущенной. То есть если не сделать close(), и выходить из программы обычным крестиком(Вверху справа) то программа остается висеть в диспечере.

Comment: close закрывает, лишь виджет(класс формы), что там у вас далее происходит и как у вас реализована структура программы только может объяснить почему не происходит очистка памяти.

Comment: Спасибо всем кто откликнулся! Я удивлен как вас много)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QDialog` не реализует свой метод `close`, стало быть смотрим в базовом:

> bool QWidget::close () [slot]
>
> Closes this widget. Returns `true` if the widget was closed; otherwise returns `false`.
>
> First it sends the widget a `QCloseEvent`. The widget is hidden if it accepts the close event. If it ignores the event, nothing happens. The default implementation of `QWidget::closeEvent()` accepts the close event.
>
> If the widget has the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` flag, the widget is also deleted. A close events is delivered to the widget no matter if the widget is visible or not.
>
> The `QApplication::lastWindowClosed()` signal is emitted when the last visible primary window (i.e. window with no parent) with the `Qt::WA_QuitOnClose` attribute set is closed. By default this attribute is set for all widgets except transient windows such as splash screens, tool windows, and popup menus.

Т. е. при вызове `close` экземпляр окна может быть уничтожен, если выставлен флаг `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`.

Но можно вовсе не использовать ни `close`, ни `destroy`, а только создание экземпляра на стеке, вместо поля класса, как похоже, делает автор вопроса.

Я, обычно для модальных диалогов создаю небольшой класс с функцией `getResult`:

```
class MyTableDialog(QtGui.QDialog, ):
  __ui = None
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(MyTableDialog, self).__init__(parent)
    ui = self.__ui = Ui_MyTableDialog()
    ui.setupUi(self)
    self.__my_setup_ui()

  def GetResult(self, *args, **kwds):
    self.__set_args_to_ui(*args, **kwds)
    if self.exec_() != self.Accepted:
      return
    return self.__get_res_from_ui()

  def __my_setup_ui(self):
    "Здесь дополнительно инициализируем интерфейс и связываем сигналы" 
  def __set_args_to_ui(self, *args, **kwds):
    "Здесь устанавливаем данные в элементы интерфейса"
  def __get_res_from_ui(self):
    "Здесь вытаскиваем введённые в интерфейсе данные"

# Пример использования
class MyMainWindow(...):
  def GetUserTable(self, *args, **kwds):
    res = MyTableDialog(self).GetResult(*args, **kwds)
    if res is None:
      logging.info('Пользователь отказался от ввода')
    else:
      self.__parse_user_table_input(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

Читаем [документацию к `QWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#close):

> Closes this widget. Returns true if the widget was closed; otherwise
>   returns false.

Как можно заметить, здесь ничего не говорится об освобождении памяти, занимаемой объектом `QWidget`.

Не могу сказать, как точно работает менеджер памяти в python, приведу код на c++:

```
void foo()
{
  QWidget w;
  w.show();
  ....
  w.close();
}

void bar()
{
  QWidget* pw = new QWidget();
  w->show();
  ....
  w->close();
}
```

Пояснения:

Функция `foo()`:

- создаёт объект класса `QWidget`,
- показывает окно,
- делает что-то ещё...,
- закрывает окно,
- объект `w` уничтожается при выходе из области видимости, память отведённая для него освобождается.

Функция `bar()`:

- создаёт объект класса `QWidget` **в динамической памяти**,
- показывает окно,
- делает что-то ещё...,
- закрывает окно,
- объект `*pw` не уничтожается, а память им занимаемая не освобождается, т.к. программист намеренно не вызывает оператор `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

Выдержки из Qt Assistant:
Оригинал:

> bool QWidget::close() Closes this widget. Returns true if the widget
>   was closed; otherwise returns false.
>
> First it sends the widget a QCloseEvent. The widget is hidden if it
>   accepts the close event. If it ignores the event, nothing happens. The
>   default implementation of QWidget::closeEvent() accepts the close
>   event.
>
> If the widget has the Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose flag, the widget is also
>   deleted. A close events is delivered to the widget no matter if the
>   widget is visible or not.
>
> The QApplication::lastWindowClosed() signal is emitted when the last
>   visible primary window (i.e. window with no parent) with the
>   Qt::WA_QuitOnClose attribute set is closed. By default this attribute
>   is set for all widgets except transient windows such as splash
>   screens, tool windows, and popup menus.

Перевод:

> Закрывает этот виджет. Возвращает `true`, если этот виджет был закрыт;
>   иначе `false`.
>
> Сначала посылается в `QCloseEvent`. Виджет скрывается если это событие
>   разрешается. Если нет, тот ничего не происходит. По умолчанию
>   наследование от `QWidget::closeEvent()` разрешает закрывающее событие.
>
> Если виджет имеет Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose флаг(Примечание от меня,
>   задавать через 
>       setAttribute(), например, this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose)), то он ещё и будет удалён.
>   Событие закрытия не доставляется в виджет в не зависимости от его
>   видимости.
>
> Сигнал `QApplication::lastWindowClosed()` будет произведён, когда
>   последнее видимое главное окно(т.е. окно без родителя), с
>   установленным атрибутом `Qt::WA_QuitOnClose`, было закрыто. По
>   умолчанию этот атрибут установлен для всех виджетов, кроме
>   переходных(временных окон) таких, как частички на экране, оконные
>   инструменты и всплывающие меню.

Оригинал:

> void QWidget::destroy(bool destroyWindow = true, bool
>   destroySubWindows = true) Frees up window system resources. Destroys
>   the widget window if destroyWindow is true.
>
> destroy() calls itself recursively for all the child widgets, passing
>   destroySubWindows for the destroyWindow parameter. To have more
>   control over destruction of subwidgets, destroy subwidgets selectively
>   first.
>
> This function is usually called from the QWidget destructor.

Перевод:

> Освобождает окно системных ресурсов. Вызывает конструктор виджета
>   окна, если параметр `destroyWindow` равен `true`. `destroy()` вызывает
>   себя рекурсивно для всех дочерних виджетов, проходя
>   `destroySubWindows` для параметра `destroyWindow`. Для того, чтобы
>   иметь более гибкое управление нужно разрушить "подвиджеты" раньше.
>
> Эта функция обычно вызывается в QWidget деструкторе.

Заранее извиняюсь за вольный перевод, старался наиболее правильно перевести.

Comment: Почитайте вопрос автора внимательнее, у него диалог. У диалога другая документация ;)

Comment: @ixSci а разве QDialog не наследуется от QWidget ?)

Comment: Наследуется, но у Вас приведена документация `QWindow`, а не `QWidget`

Comment: Скорее всего ixSci прав. Я же привел пример что close не освобождает память! Я пытался читать документацию, но с английским у меня все плохо.

Comment: @ixSci Изменил перевод, сделал его из документации по QWidget.