# Как по нажатию на кнопку закрыть диалоговое окно Qt?

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Есть MainWindow и Dialog по нажатию на кнопку в MainWindow открывается окно.
Как сделать что бы по нажатию на кнопку(pushButton) в Dialog закрывалось это диалоговое окно?

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

}
```

Comment: посмотрите вот этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519404/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-qt-close-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-destroy/519524#519524

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить вызов `close()` в слоте

```
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    close();
}
```